# Hibernate - record date attribute first got data

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data

I want to record the date that a attribute in a entity first got data.

For example:

```
@Entity
public class Sales(){

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String salesNote;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    private Date salesNoteCreationDate;
}
```

I tried to do this in the Service layer by comparing:

```
    if (!saleView.getsalesNote().isEmpty() && saleDb.getPlan().getNotes().isEmpty()) {
        Date salesNoteCreationDate = new Date();
        saleView.setsalesNoteCreationDate(salesNoteCreationDate);
    }
```

This only half worked, because the `salesNoteCreationDate` isn't sent to the UI, if the above test fails and the date is not set the `null` value in `saleView` overwrites the `saleDb` value which may hold a valid date.

I suspect there is a simpler way either through using `@Version` or a Hibernate Listener - having looked at the [Hibernate docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#events-jpa-callbacks-example) I am none the wiser on this particular issue.

Comment: I probably don't understand the question properly, but why don't you just check if `salesNoteCreationDate` is `null` before setting it? Also, what does your UI have to do with this?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just put this logic where it belongs: encapsulated in the entity, rather than in the UI?

```
@Entity
public class Sale {

    private String note;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    private Date noteCreationDate;

    public void setNote(String note) {
        if (this.note == null && note != null) {
            this.noteCreationDate = new Date();
        }
        this.note = note;
    }
}
```

Note that I renamed your entity to Sale (since an instance of that class probably represents *one* sale, and not multiple ones). Also note that I removed the `sales` prefix on your fields, which are fields of the Sale class,making this prefix redundant.